# Add rows accumulated by current month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to translate my hard coded SQL script into a dynamic?

My problem with this code is that, it still adding the SEPT-DEC it should be zero since we are not yet covered this month

```
  SELECT *,
  [JAN] [JAN TO JAN]  ,  
  [JAN] + [FEB]  [JAN TO FEB] ,
  [JAN] + [FEB] + [MAR] [JAN TO MAR],
  [JAN] + [FEB] + [MAR] + [APR] [JAN TO APR]    ,
  [JAN] + [FEB] + [MAR] + [APR] + [MAY] [JAN TO MAY]    ,
  [JAN] + [FEB] + [MAR] + [APR] + [MAY] + [JUN] [JAN TO JUN]    ,
  [JAN] + [FEB] + [MAR] + [APR] + [MAY] + [JUN] + [JUL] [JAN TO JUL],
  [JAN] + [FEB] + [MAR] + [APR] + [MAY] + [JUN] + [JUL] + [AUG] [JAN TO AUG],
  [JAN] + [FEB] + [MAR] + [APR] + [MAY] + [JUN] + [JUL] + [AUG] + [SEP] [JAN TO SEP],
  [JAN] + [FEB] + [MAR] + [APR] + [MAY] + [JUN] + [JUL] + [AUG] + [SEP] + [OCT]  [JAN TO OCT],
  [JAN] + [FEB] + [MAR] + [APR] + [MAY] + [JUN] + [JUL] + [AUG] + [SEP] + [OCT] + [NOV] [JAN TO NOV],
  [JAN] + [FEB] + [MAR] + [APR] + [MAY] + [JUN] + [JUL] + [AUG] + [SEP] + [OCT] + [NOV] + [DEC] [JAN TO DEC]
  FROM TEST_CHANNEL_YTD
```

My table

[image]

Expected Result:

Starts from JAN then Added the succeeding covered months.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68658128/transfer-large-amount-of-data-from-text-file-to-ms-sql-server-database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can UNPIVOT your data, use the window function `sum() over()` to calculate the running total and then PIVOT the results.

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select Year
              ,Channels
              ,Col
              ,Amt
         From TEST_CHANNEL_YTD A
         Cross Apply ( 
                      Select Col
                            ,Amt = sum(Amt) over (Order by Seq)
                       From (values ('Jan to Jan',1,Jan)
                                   ,('Jan to Feb',2,Feb)
                                   ,('Jan to Mar',3,Mar)
                                   ,('Jan to Apr',4,Apr)
                                   ,('Jan to May',5,May)
                                   ,('Jan to Jun',6,Jun)
                                   ,('Jan to Jul',7,Jul)
                                   ,('Jan to Aug',8,Aug)
                                   ,('Jan to Sep',9,Sep)
                                   ,('Jan to Oct',10,Oct)
                                   ,('Jan to Nov',11,Nov)
                                   ,('Jan to Dec',12,Dec)
                               ) V (Col,Seq,Amt)
                        ) B
       ) src 
 Pivot ( sum(Amt) for Col in ([Jan to Jan],[Jan to Feb],[Jan to Mar],[Jan to Apr],[Jan to May],[Jan to Jun],[Jan to Jul],[Jan to Aug],[Jan to Sep],[Jan to Oct],[Jan to Nov],[Jan to Dec]) ) pvt
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much John Cappelletti. It works !

Comment: Very good. Two points: `SUM OVER` should normally always have `ROW UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` because the default is `RANGE`, and although it doesn't change the results if the ordering is unique, it is more efficient. Secondly, you could place the pivot *inside* the apply, which simplifies the query and removes the neccessity for an outer subquery

Answer (score 2):

You can go for CROSS APPLY and conditional grouping as given below:

```sql
declare @table table(year int, channel char(10), jan int,feb int, mar int, apr int, may int, jun int, jul int, aug int, sep int, oct int, nov int, dec int)

insert into @table 
values
(2021,'channel1',1193,11,5,2,2,5,0,0,0,0,0,0),
(2021,'channel2',3228,373,156,106,76,86,17,13,0,0,0,0);

select year, channel,
sum(case when mnumber <= 1 then ca.mvalue end) as [Jan To Jan],
sum(case when mnumber <= 2 then ca.mvalue end) as [Jan To Feb],
sum(case when mnumber <= 3 then ca.mvalue end) as [Jan To Mar] ,
sum(case when mnumber <= 4 then ca.mvalue end) as [Jan To Apr],
sum(case when mnumber <= 5 then ca.mvalue end) as [Jan To May] ,
sum(case when mnumber <= 6 then ca.mvalue end) as [Jan To Jun],
sum(case when mnumber <= 7 then ca.mvalue end) as [Jan To Jul] ,
sum(case when mnumber <= 8 then ca.mvalue end) as [Jan To Aug],
sum(case when mnumber <= 9 then ca.mvalue end) as [Jan To Sep], 
sum(case when mnumber <= 10 then ca.mvalue end) as [Jan To Oct],
sum(case when mnumber <= 11 then ca.mvalue end) as [Jan To Nov], 
sum(case when mnumber <= 12 then ca.mvalue end) as [Jan To Dec]
from @table as t
cross apply
(values
(1,t.jan),
(2,t.feb),
(3,t.mar),
(4,t.apr),
(5,t.may),
(6,t.jun), 
(7,t.jul), 
(8,t.aug), 
(9,t.sep), 
(10,t.oct),
(11,t.nov),
(12,t.dec))as ca(mnumber,mvalue)
group by year, channel
```

| year | channel | Jan To Jan | Jan To Feb | Jan To Mar | Jan To Apr | Jan To May | Jan To Jun | Jan To Jul | Jan To Aug | Jan To Sep | Jan To Oct | Jan To Nov | Jan To Dec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | channel1 | 1193 | 1204 | 1209 | 1211 | 1213 | 1218 | 1218 | 1218 | 1218 | 1218 | 1218 | 1218 |
| 2021 | channel2 | 3228 | 3601 | 3757 | 3863 | 3939 | 4025 | 4042 | 4055 | 4055 | 4055 | 4055 | 4055 |

Comment: Solid approach.  You could drop the month names in the cross apply  +1

Comment: Hi Venkataraman R it works too! .. but missing 'Jan to Jan'  field :)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, Thanks. you are right. I have updated my answer.